# Using CURL to post form data to a webpage

Tags: java, c, linux, unix, curl

I need to post  one attribute value present in a form to server using curl.

```
<form action="process.php" method="post">
     <input tupe="text" name="userName" />
</form>.
```

Now I want to post this form to the server. How can I achive it using curl.

Comment: This is clearly a spam attempt. Flagged.

Comment: @balusc - looks like a genuine mistake, possibly some overly exuberant mark & copy/paste. OP's other posts are clean, will let go this time.

Comment: May I know why u think it is spam.

Comment: there was some random text after your questions, which simply said "wallpapers", etc. It has been currently edited out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use the option "-d" for posting data.

```
curl -d "userName=narendra" http://example.com/process.php
```